# sites.php setup

Tags: multi-sites

I am trying to do multi-site the following way:

http://domain.com/site1

http://domain.com/site2

sites.php:

```
 $sites['domain.com.site1'] = 'default';
 $sites['domain.com.site2'] = 'site2';
```

I then went into my drupal root and did:

```
ln -s . site1
ln -s . site2
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? It appears to work, but I am not sure if symlinking is the proper way.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `$sites['domain.com.site1'] = 'site1';` (not `default`)
`$sites['domain.com.site2'] = 'site2';` ?

Comment: Check out: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site which answers your question. From # 5:  "Make symbolic links if you are using a subdirectory such as example.com/subdir and not a subdomain such as subd.example.com (see the subdirectory multi-site section below for details). "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes- you did this right :)

cp example.sites.php as sites.php, set the sites array, set the symlink, and you're set!

Comment: Are there are security issues with the fact that you can so /site1/site1/site1...?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean- all sites should be located in the /sites/ directory and have a unique settings.php... This shouldn't pose a security risk.

Comment: I mean I can do http://domain.com/site1/site1/site1 because of the symlink to its parent directory.

Comment: You're still only accessing the parent directory- how would this pose a risk?

Comment: @ChrisMuench security is what I was thinking too when I saw this.  I haven't spent time on it, but I expect there very likely are implications here.  Check rewrite rules for things like protecting private file directories carefully, and post any worrying findings.  Circular symlinks are almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the sites array in sites.php as:

```
$sites['multi.devs'] = 'multi.dev';
$sites['sub1.multi.devs'] = 'multi.devs';
$sites['sub2.multi.devs'] = 'multi.devs';
```

and in your hosts file you can set the hostname as

```
127.0.0.1       multi.devs
127.0.0.1       sub1.multi.devs
127.0.0.1       sub2.multi.devs
```

Also need to entry them in httpd-vhost.conf file. Like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "projects/drupal_multi/"
    ServerName   multi.devs
    ErrorLog    "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog   "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

You need to do this for each of sub site. DocumentRoot will be the same the server name will be change for each of them.